# Lookup filter criteria

Tags: salesforce

I have a junction object between Opportunity and Contact. On the Contact filed in this junction object i need to restrict the contacts that user can select. The user should only be able to select the contacts that are associated with the Opportunities account. I tried to filter the Contact field on the junction object, but somehow I am unable to do so. I am not getting any option to use Opportunity's account there.
 Can somebody pls suggest how can I filter this. Its very urgent!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set up a validation rule on your custom objects to not allow a save if the contact selected isn't associated with the same account and the opportunity.